# How should i upload image on cloudinary with react?

Tags: reactjs, cloudinary

i have been implementing a functionality where i need to upload images to the cloudinary from react application but i am getting status code 500. My code is:

```js
 const handleImageUpload = () => {
        const { files } = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]')
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', files[0]);
        // replace this with your upload preset name
        formData.append('upload_preset', 'Preset name');
        const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/data',
            'Authorization': 'cloudinary://api_key:api_secret@apurvsingla',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        }
        };

        // replace cloudname with your Cloudinary cloud_name
        return axios.post('https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/apurvsingla/image/upload', options)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example, i believe this will help you:

```
function uploadFile(file) {
   var url = `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/apurvsingla/upload`;
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   var fd = new FormData();
   xhr.open('POST', url, true);
   xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
   fd.append('file', file);
   xhr.send(fd);
}
```

Checkout full example in the link below:

https://codepen.io/team/Cloudinary/pen/QgpyOK